# List all children in firebase database web

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase so go gentle... I have a database formatted as such:

[image]

All i want is to be able to loop through all the children of Comments so I can find the message/username. I'm doing this with web. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the forEach method on the snapshot

```
firebase.database().ref('/Comments')
       .once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
              snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                   const comment = childSnapshot.val();
                   // ....
              }
        });
```